# Make an XSLT result document be processed by a “parent” XSLT document, recursively

Tags: xml, xslt

I have document grandchild.xml whose result after being processed with granchild.xsl must be forwarded to child.xsl, then it must be finally processed and output by parent.xsl.

I have tried adding an `xml-stylesheet` element to the result document, expecting it to processed using by the referenced XSL stylesheet, but nothing happened.

What is the correct declaration to accomplish this task? I have searched a lot on Internet, with no results.

Comment: If I understand you correctly (that you're expecting the browser to be able to recursively process a generated XML using XSLT) then I think you're out of luck. To paraphrase a quote I saw on SO, browsers haven't watched "Inception" and don't know how to "go deeper"

Comment: You understand me right and well, I actually even searched for “XSL Inception”, lol.
Then, if it is not possible, I don’t really see any really useful or productive use of XSLT vs inserting HTML content as strings server side. or maybe I am not really getting the point of XSLT?

Comment: XSLT tranformation of XML has many uses, and we use it all over the place when generating particular bits of HTML... it's a very powerful language

Comment: One can always perform a single, multi-pass transformation within a browser. Are you interested to see a code example?

Comment: @DimitreNovatchev does it address my original request? I am not sure.

Comment: @user1598585, Yes, you simply `xsl:import` one stylesheet module into another.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless anybody knows any better, I believe the ability to recursively process XSLT output on a browser is impossible.

To prove it, I have just tried the following in IE8, FF14 and Chrome...

**level1.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
<?xml-stylesheet title="XSL_formatting" type="text/xsl" href="level1.xsl"?>
<data>
  <id>Level 1 data</id>
</data>
```

**level1.xsl**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
   <xsl:template match="/">
     <?xml-stylesheet title="XSL_formatting" type="text/xsl" href="level2.xsl"?>
     <data2>
       <id2>Level 2: <xsl:value-of select="/data/id"/></id2>
     </data2>
   </xsl:template>   
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**level2.xsl**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
   <xsl:template match="/">
     <html>
       <body>
         <b>Level 3:</b> <xsl:value-of select="/data2/id2"/>
       </body>
     </html>
   </xsl:template>   
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The result from all 3 browsers is simply to display `Level 2: Level 1 Data`.

Comment: Is this behaviour specific to web-browsers or can I expect the same of server-side XSLT implementations?

Comment: @user, I would very much expect the same from server-side... although obviously on the server-side you can check the resultant output of the transformation, and if necessary run it again against another XSLT

Comment: Exactly what I was expecting and you just confirmed my idea, of what I am now thinking that I will do. Thanks for your time.

Comment: You're welcome @user, good luck with the rest of your project :-)

Comment: @freefaller, But one can always perform a single, multi-pass transformation within a browser.

Comment: @Dimitre, I would be very interested to see how that would be done

Comment: It's fairly straightforward, you just do `<xsl:variable name="pass1"><xsl:apply-templates /></xsl:variable><xsl:apply-templates select="$pass1" />`.

Comment: @Flynn1179 have you got any link where I can find a good explanation of what an `apply-templates` element does? I have tried to understand but I just cannot get it.

Comment: @user1598585, `xsl:apply-templates` ... aplies templates to the nodes selected by the XPath expression specified in its `select` attribute. For good books on XSLT and XPath, see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/339930/any-good-xslt-tutorial-book-blog-site-online/341589#341589

Comment: This is not a valid experiment because the result document of level1.xsl will not have an `xml-stylesheet` processing instruction in it. To output a processing instruction, you need to use `<xsl:processing-instruction>`.

Answer (score 1):

**Here is an example of multi-pass transformation within a browser**:

**Let us have this source XML document**:

```
<?xml-stylesheet title="XSL_formatting"
  type="text/xsl" href="MultiPassBrowser.xsl"?>
<nums>
  <num>01</num>
  <num>02</num>
  <num>03</num>
  <num>04</num>
  <num>05</num>
  <num>06</num>
  <num>07</num>
  <num>08</num>
  <num>09</num>
  <num>10</num>
</nums>
```

**Let us have these two XSLT transformations**:

## MultiPassBrowser1.xsl

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
  <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
  </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="num/text()">
  <xsl:value-of select=". *2"/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

and

## MultiPassBrowser2.xsl

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*" mode="pass2">
  <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*" mode="pass2"/>
  </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="num" mode="pass2">
  <p><xsl:value-of select=". +1"/></p>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The first transformation copies the XML document "as-is", but with the string value of every `num` element multiplied by 2.

The second transformation copies the XML document "as-is", but with the string value of every `num` element incremented.

If the second transformation is applied on the result of the first, the final values, obtained from the initial `num` elements must be 3, 5, 7, ..., 21.

**Here is the transformation that glues these two together**:

## MultiPassBrowser.xsl

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:ext="http://exslt.org/common"
 xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" 
 exclude-result-prefixes="ext msxsl">
 <xsl:import href="file:///C:/Temp/delete/MultiPassBrowser1.xsl"/>
 <xsl:import href="file:///C:/Temp/delete/MultiPassBrowser2.xsl"/>
 <xsl:output method="html"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <msxsl:script language="JScript" implements-prefix="ext">
     this['node-set'] =  function (x) {
      return x;
      }
 </msxsl:script>

 <xsl:template match="/">
  <html>
      <xsl:variable name="vrtfPass1">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="/*"/>
      </xsl:variable>

      <xsl:apply-templates select="ext:node-set($vrtfPass1)/*/*"
                           mode="pass2"/>
  </html>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**The result, when the XML file is opened with both IE, Firefox, Safari and Opera, is the correct, expected one**:

```
<html>
   <p>3</p>
   <p>5</p>
   <p>7</p>
   <p>9</p>
   <p>11</p>
   <p>13</p>
   <p>15</p>
   <p>17</p>
   <p>19</p>
   <p>21</p>
</html>
```

**Explanation**:

1. The primary stylesheet module (the one referenced in the XML document PI) imports the two stylesheet modules that contain the separate transformations.
2. The result of the first transformation is captured in the variavle `$vrtfPass1`.
3. In XSLT 1.0 such variable is of the infamous "RTF" (Result Tree Fragment) type and cannot be operated directly (only copying and the `string()` function can be used on an RTF). Here we use a portable variant of the `xxx:node-set()` extension function, that works both in IE and in the other four major browsers. **This portable extension was first proposed by @DavidCarlisle and the original can be found in [his blog](http://dpcarlisle.blogspot.com/2007_05_01_archive.html)**.
4. Templates in mode "pass2" are then applied on the node-set, to which we converted, in the step above, the RTF variable. All templates in the second imported stylesheet module are in mode "pass2", thus they are selected for execution.
5. The final result is produced.

Comment: I like it, and almost fully understand it ;-)  It's still not quite what the OP was asking for (which I still believe to be impossible) but it's an excellent alternative. +1

Comment: @freefaller, And if there are tens or hundreds of transformations to be chained, this is done very conveniently, using the FXSL template `compose-flist`. You can see it here: http://fxsl.cvs.sourceforge.net/viewvc/fxsl/fxsl-xslt2/Tests/testCompose.xsl?revision=1.1&view=markup